# Does Oracle GoldenGate replicates import operation

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

Will any import (by data pump) operation on Oracle Database be captured by GoldenGate Integrated Extract ?

Comment: yes, any ddl or dml recorded in redo log or archivelogs will be replicated.

Comment: There's nothing 'magic' about inserts that come from an import operation.  An export .dmp file is just a binary representation of a bunch of CREATE and INSERT statements.  The import operation simply replays those statements.  As far as the db is concerned, an INSERT from data pump is no different than an INSERT from sqlplus.